# Redirect 301 every url with index.php? to www.domain.com/subpage.htm

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I try to redirect URLs like : http://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_acesef&limitstart=100&tag=barajas&view=tags
To : 
http://www.domain.com/subpage.html
That is, any URL "estrange" that begins like www.domain.com/index.php? redirects to a unique www.domain.com/subpage.html

How can I do this in .htaccess ?

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself. The best I have found to this case is :

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /subpage.html? [L,R=301]
```

In the case there are something before query string (QSA) index.php?
like in this url :
domain.com/directorio/index.php?id=123

or

domain.com/directorio/index.php?txt=alert

and want it redirects to :
domain.com/subpage.html (Without QueryString)

you should do this :

```
RewriteRule index\.php$ /subpage.html? [L,R=301]
```

wiithoout first ^